# How to close $uibModal from a function if modal is attached to the same scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-ui

I receive `close is not a function` when trying to close a modal window created by `$uibModal.open()`

I have reduced the problem to minimal code:

```
    var app = angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

    app.controller('DemoContrller', function($scope, $uibModal) {
      var vm = this;
      var myModalInstance = null;

      vm.openModal = function() {

        myModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                  animation: true,
                  templateUrl: 'modalTemplate.html',
                  scope: $scope // important - want to reuse current scope and controller and not create new
              }).result.then(function() {
                  console.log('fully closed with successful validation');
              });

      };


      vm.onApplyModal = function() {

          console.log('doing some validation and closing only if succeeded');

          // ??? close is not a function, myModalInstance is a Promise

          console.log(myModalInstance);
          myModalInstance.close();
      };

    })
```

Please see my Plunk here: [Cannot close uibmodal from a function in the same scope](https://plnkr.co/edit/8Mm5cA9v6ksJ1fYoaVSN?p=preview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 myModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                  animation: true,
                  templateUrl: 'modalTemplate.html',
                  scope: $scope // important - want to reuse current scope and controller and not create new
              }).result.then(function() {
                  console.log('fully closed with successful validation');
              });
```

First assign variable, then chain:

```
 myModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                  animation: true,
                  templateUrl: 'modalTemplate.html',
                  scope: $scope // important - want to reuse current scope and controller and not create new
              });
myModalInstance .result.then(function() {
                  console.log('fully closed with successful validation');
              });
```